clean-up a terrain mesh from dem (blender-gis) to extrude
I'm working with a terrain mesh from a geotiff based on gps survey.
The surface covered by the survey is irregular, so I create an irregular mask with GRASS.
I imported geotiff with Blender-Gis with success, but the object has 256 non-Manifold Edges and 1470 Non-Flat Faces.

I presumed that this causes the fact that I can't extrude the entire object's edge. I want to create a "solid" from the plane mesh, because it's necessary to modify it with boolean difference with a cast "swale" (sort of ditch) object.
I tried to clean-up with 3D-Print addon, but I didn't undestand because the result of deleting zero faces and loose geometry is some strange faces without any vertex and edge.

Thank you in advance, and excuse for the probably english mistakes

It's hard to understand what your problem is... but you can try (starting from the 2d surface) to merge by distance (edit mode, select all a and merge m by distance) before extruding, and you will have a good solid. The borders with weird faces are unfortunately the result of something you didn't explain well in your question.

I found a solution! In GRASS I used a region bigger than the raster layer, and I exported the geotiff with a value for nullvalue. In Blender-GIS I imported the geotiff as DEM mesh (not dispacement texture) with 1 step, to give a maximum resolution. The mesh resulted was with a concavity towards a plane of the value for nullvalue defined. So it is possible to create a plane of the same dimension of the region, at a z level less than value for nullvalue, and with boolean difference split the mesh at this plane. The result is a volume without manifold or non-flat faces!!! Yeahhhh
